# Cual seria la mejor forma de manejar la cadencia de disparo de las naves en mi juego?

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

En mi código actual las naves enemigas disparan cada frame del juego.
Como puedo hacer que esos disparos sean cada cierto tiempo, 2 segundos por ejemplo?

Mi codigo:

Bullet.h:

```
class Bullet {
private:

sf::Sprite sprite;

sf::Vector2f speed;


int posX, posY;

Bullet(int _posX, int _posY, sf::Texture &_texture);

public:

friend class BulletFactory;

void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
void reset();
void setSpeed(float _speed);
sf::Sprite render();
sf::FloatRect bounds(){
    return sprite.getGlobalBounds();
}
};

class BulletFactory{
private:
sf::Texture texture;
public:
BulletFactory(){
    texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/10_Network/Media/Textures/misil2.png");
}

Bullet create(int _posX, int _posY){
    return {_posX, _posY, texture};
}
};
```

Bullet.cpp:

```
Bullet::Bullet(int _posX, int _posY, sf::Texture &_texture) {

sprite.setTexture(_texture);
sprite.rotate(-90);
sprite.setScale(0.1f, 0.1f);

posX = _posX;
posY = _posY;

sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

speed.y = -500.0f;
}


void Bullet::update(sf::Time deltaTime){

sprite.move(0, speed.y * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}

sf::Sprite Bullet::render(){
return sprite;
}

void Bullet::reset(){
speed.x = 0.0f;
speed.y = 0.0f;
}

void Bullet::setSpeed(float _speed){
speed.y = _speed;
}
```

enemy.h:

```
class Enemy {
private:
sf::Sprite sprite;

float speed = 200.0f ;

Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture &_texture);
public:
friend class EnemyFactory;

sf::FloatRect bounds(){
    return sprite.getGlobalBounds();
}

sf::Vector2f getPosition(){
    return sprite.getPosition();
}
sf::Sprite render();
void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
void reset();
};

class EnemyFactory{
private:
sf::Texture texture;
public:
EnemyFactory(){
    texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/03_World/Media/Textures/Raptor.png");
}

Enemy create(int _maxX, int _maxY){
    return {_maxX, _maxY, texture};
}
};
```

Enemy.cpp:

```
Enemy::Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture &_texture) {
sprite.setTexture(_texture);
sprite.rotate(180);
sprite.setScale(0.8f, 0.8f);

sprite.setPosition(1+rand()%640,rand() % 400 - 500); 
}

sf::Sprite Enemy::render(){
return sprite;
}

void Enemy::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
sprite.move(0.0f, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());

if (sprite.getPosition().y > 480+51.2){
    sprite.setPosition(1+rand()%640,rand() % 400 - 500);  
}
}

void Enemy::reset(){
speed = 0;
}
```

game.h:

```
class Game {
private:
sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;

ScrollingBackground background;

Aircraft aircraft;

std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
EnemyFactory enemy;

std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
std::vector<Bullet> enemybullets;
BulletFactory bullet;
private:
void proccesEvent();
void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
void proccesCollisions();
void render();
public:
Game();
void run();
};
```

game.cpp:

```
Game::Game(){
mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "ventana SFML"); 
mWindow->setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

for (int i=0; i<7; i++){
    enemies.push_back(enemy.create(640,480));
}   
}

void Game::proccesEvent(){
sf::Event event;

while(mWindow->pollEvent(event)){
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
        mWindow->close();
    }

    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space){
        bullets.push_back(bullet.create((aircraft.getPosition().x+15), (aircraft.getPosition().y+40)));
    }

}
}

void Game::update(sf::Time deltaTime){

background.update(mWindow, deltaTime);

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)){
    aircraft.Up();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)){
    aircraft.Down(mWindow);
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
    aircraft.Left();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)){
    aircraft.Right(mWindow);
}

for (int j=0; j<enemies.size(); j++){
    enemies[j].update(deltaTime);
    enemybullets.push_back(bullet.create((enemies[j].getPosition().x), (enemies[j].getPosition().y)));
}

for (int j=0; j<enemybullets.size(); j++){
    enemybullets[j].setSpeed(500.0f);
    enemybullets[j].update(deltaTime);
}

for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++){
    bullets[i].update(deltaTime);
}

aircraft.update(deltaTime);
}

void Game::render(){
mWindow->clear();
mWindow->draw(background.render());
for (int j=0; j<enemies.size(); j++){
    mWindow->draw(enemies[j].render());
}
for (int i=0; i<enemybullets.size(); i++){
    mWindow->draw(enemybullets[i].render());
}
for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++){
    mWindow->draw(bullets[i].render());
}
mWindow->draw(aircraft.Render());

mWindow->display();
}

void Game::run(){
sf::Clock clock;
while(mWindow->isOpen()){
    sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();
    proccesEvent();
    proccesCollisions();
    update(deltaTime);
    render();
}
}
```

no agregue en game.cpp la funcion proccesCollisions para no alargar el codigo inecesariamente.

Comment: sigue siendo mucho para mirar.. donde se crean los disparos y donde se procesan???

Comment: en **Game::update(...)** cuando se actualiza el vector de naves enemigas se crean las balas enemigas en la posicion de las naves. luego se recorre el vector de balas enemigas para actualizarlas

Comment: no deberia tener que saber cada nave cuando crear las balas? y devolverselas al juego cuando corresponda? asi cada nave tiene su propio contador de tiempo y sabe cuando disparar.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte con más detalle deberías mostrar el código de `Enemy`. La decisión del disparo debería delegarse a esa clase tal y como te muestro en mi respuesta.

Comment: ¿Pudiste mirar alguna de las respuestas que te ofrecimos?

Comment: Muchas Gracias por sus respuestas @OscarGarcia ya  agregue el codigo de de la clase **Enemy**

Comment: Hecho, he editado mi respuesta, espero que sea de tu agrado el resultado :)

Comment: Muchas gracias es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Recuerda votar positivo las respuestas que te hayan sido de utilidad y marcar como respuesta correcta la que mejor lo haya hecho. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en la que estructuras los eventos termina complicando la delegación de decisiones de una nave al bucle principal, cosa que no es buena idea.

Sin hacer modificaciones profundas en tu lógica de programación, te recomendaría hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

- Durante la actualización de los enemigos comprobar si éstos deben disparar (dicha decisión también podría hacerse en la función `update()` y allí, por ejemplo, modificar un indicador (flag) que sea leído posteriormente.
- Implementar en la clase `Enemy` la lógica de decisión. En mi ejemplo lo hago en una función propia, si conociera la clase `Enemy` quizá pudiera implementar la lógica en la función `update()`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de implementación usando una función adicional:

**game.cpp**

```
for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++){
    enemies[j].update(deltaTime);
    /* Llamamos a la función de la clase `Enemy` a la que delegamos
      la decisión de realizar el disparo o no */
    if (enemies[j].fireEvent(deltaTime)) {
        /* Si devuelve true entonces efectuamos el disparo */
        enemybullets.push_back(
            bullet.create(
                enemies[j].getPosition().x,
                enemies[j].getPosition().y
            )
        );
    }
}
```

De esta manera delegamos la decisión de disparar a la implementación de los enemigos, de modo que debemos agregar a su clase:

```
class Enemy {
    sf::Time shootTime, delayShoot;
    bool Enemy::fireEvent(sf::Time deltaTime) {
        /* Incrementamos delayShoot el tiempo que ha transcurrido */
        delayShoot += deltaTime;
        /* ¿Hemos superado el tiempo mínimo entre disparos? */
        if (delayShoot >= shootTime) {
          /* Restamos el tiempo entre disparos, en caso de una pausa muy
            elevada eliminamos el resto de eventos pasados */
          while (delayShoot >= shootTime) {
            delayShoot -= shootTime;
          }
          /* Indicamos que debemos disparar */
          return true;
       }
       /* Indicamos que en este momento no debe generarse un disparo */
       return false;
    }
}
```

Como no muestras el código de la clase `Enemy` no puedo hacer modificaciones del constructor para inicializar dichas variables (`delayShoot = sf::seconds(0f)` y `shootTime = sf::seconds(2f)`), pero la idea es que uses `shootTime` para definir la cadencia (el intervalo de tiempo mínimo entre dos disparos).

---

**Edición:**

Podemos agregar estas definiciones dentro de `enemy.h` en la parte pública y privada:

```
public:
    bool isShooting = false;

private:
    sf::Time shootTime, delayShoot;
```

En `Enemy.cpp` modificamos el constructor para incluir las siguientes inicializaciones y la función `update` para modificar el valor de `isShooting`:

```
Enemy::Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture &_texture) {
    delayShoot = sf::seconds(0f);
    shootTime = sf::seconds(2f);
    /* ... */
}

void Enemy::update(sf::Time deltaTime) {
    /* Incrementamos delayShoot el tiempo que ha transcurrido */
    delayShoot += deltaTime;
    /* ¿Hemos superado el tiempo mínimo entre disparos? */
    if (delayShoot >= shootTime) {
        /* Restamos el tiempo entre disparos, en caso de una pausa muy
        elevada eliminamos el resto de eventos pasados */
        while (delayShoot >= shootTime) {
            delayShoot -= shootTime;
        }
        /* Indicamos que debemos disparar */
        isShooting = true;
    } else {
        /* Indicamos que en este momento no debe generarse un disparo */
        isShooting = false;
    }
    sprite.move(0.0f, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
    if (sprite.getPosition().y > 480+51.2){
        sprite.setPosition(1+rand()%640,rand() % 400 - 500);  
    }
}
```

Ahora vienen las modificaciones en `game.cpp`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++) {
    enemies[j].update(deltaTime);
    /* Si el enemigo está disparando agregamos una nueva bala */
    if (enemies[j].isShooting) {
        /* Si devuelve true entonces efectuamos el disparo */
        enemybullets.push_back(
            bullet.create(
                enemies[j].getPosition().x,
                enemies[j].getPosition().y
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Con estas modificaciones tus enemigos dispararán a intervalos de 2 segundos, aunque podrías agregar un componente aleatorio para que no disparen todos al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas compartir centenares de líneas de código para hacer esta pregunta:

**¿Cómo hacer que un suceso acontezca periódicamente?**

---

Para que un suceso (el disparo de un proyectil, consultar los puertos de una placa, abrir una tarea en un hilo, descargar datos de un recurso externo...) acontezca periódicamente sólo necesitas saber:

- El tiempo pasado desde el último suceso.
- La periodicidad del suceso.

#### Propuesta.

C++11 modernizó todas las operaciones de medidas de tiempo con la cabecera [`<chrono>` [image]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono), esta cabecera ofrece objetos de tipo [`time_point`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) los cuales (como su nombre indica) marcan un momento en el tiempo.

Así pues, debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Al lanzar el suceso, comprobar que restando el momento previo al momento actual da una cantidad de tiempo mayor al periodo.
2. De ser cierto, almacenar el momento actual como momento previo.
3. Volver al punto 1.

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point momento_previo = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double tiempo;
std::cout << "Esperando 0.666 segundos...\n";

do
{
    tiempo = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - momento_previo).count() / 1000.;
    std::cout << "\than pasado " << tiempo << " segundos...\n";
}
while(tiempo <= 2. / 3.);

std::cout << "Han pasado 2/3 de segundo\n";
```

El ejemplo anterior espera dos tercios de segundo en un bucle `do`-`while` antes de seguir adelante, puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yNz2pIzUv158ArHB)</kbd><sup>1</sup>.

#### SFML.

Dado que estás usando [SFML [image]](https://www.sfml-dev.org), tienes la alternativa de usar la clase [`sf::Time` [image]](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Time.php), el equivalente al código anterior en SFML sería el siguiente:

```
sf::Clock reloj;
double tiempo;
std::cout << "Esperando 0.666 segundos...\n";

do
{
    tiempo = reloj.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    std::cout << "\than pasado " << tiempo << " segundos...\n";
}
while(tiempo <= 2. / 3.);

std::cout << "Han pasado 2/3 de segundo\n";
```

#### Aplicado a tu caso.

Cada uno de los personajes con capacidad de disparar con una cierta cadencia necesitará tener su propio [reloj [image]](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Clock.php), que deberás [restablecer [image]](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Clock.php#a123e2627f2943e5ecaa1db0c7df3231b) cada vez que dispare.

---

<sup>1</sup>Al código en Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ le he añadido una espera poniendo a dormir el hilo principal, de no hacerlo el sistema me echaba por saturar la salida estándar.